# parametric-ish equation of a plane

Tags: 3d, parametric

I know that there are other questions on this site about this, but I haven't gotten from them what I want.

Say we have two points $a_1,a_2\in\Bbb R^2$. thus the line $A$ connecting them is given by
$$A=\{a_1+t(a_2-a_1):t\in\Bbb R\}$$ 
Now lets say we have 3 nonlinear points $p_1,p_2,p_3\in\Bbb R^3$. What is the set-equation of the plane $P$ which connects these points?

Comment: And apply the same idea again. Once on the line, move along this and then afain parallel to a third vector in direction of third point from one of the 'first' two as described in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of the plane passing through three not aligned points is for example

$$P=\{p_1+s\cdot (p_3-p_1)+t\cdot (p_2-p_1):s,t\in\Bbb R\}$$

Can you see why?

Comment: Ohhh you add another variable... Thats great! Thanks!

Comment: @clathratus Yes of course, since the plane is 2 dimensional. You are welcome! Bye